# handling data between remote instances

Tags: sql

We have a hr system that holds employee data and have many remote databases that use this data.  Currently we use a mixture of copying the data across periodically to the remote databases and pulling the data across using views at runtime.  Im curious as to which option you think is best.  My personal preference is to copy the data across periodically as it removes the dependency from the master databases.  However it seems both have pros and cons

Whats the best practice for this?

Thanks

p.s we have a mixture of sql2000, 2005 and s008 servers

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer will depend on what level of latency is acceptable for the other systems that use the HR data.  Is a day behind OK? an Hour? or does it need to be current?

Each instance could result in a different solution.

I prefer a data pull instead of a push. The remote decides when it needs its data and you can encapsulate all that logic on the server where it belongs.  In a push, you have to keep processes on the HR server in synch with the demands of the subsystem.

I have reservations about multiple remote databases querying a source system directly.  If some latency is not an issue, build a process on the HR system to snapshot the required data into some local tables (or a data warehouse?) and have all remotes query this data.  At the very least, build local views against the HR source and only allow remote servers rights to those.

Are you doing this across a linked server?  If so, I recommend creating synonyms on the remote that point to the HR source across the link.  This will allow you to move source data locations around and only have to change your synonym definition.

Comment: ok.  What about this scenario.  Developer A works on HR System.  Developer B works on Remote System.  Developer A knows nothing about the remote systems.  He makes a change to the hr system which breaks the code the remote system uses or something similar.  The remote system which does a pull now doesnt work.  With a push the data would still be present.  We have had that happen here.

Comment: The same scenario could happen with a push. Dev A seems capable of screwing up anything!  This is why you have a change control process and preferably a test platform.  I just like having all processes required by a Remote Server to be encapsulated on that remote server.  No one has to wonder "How does this EMP_PUSH table get populated?" and then go talk to someone with rights to the HR System to find out.  It's all right there on your local server.